# Why destination IP is included in the TCP socket identifier?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

We know that TCP sockets can be identified by origin IP, origin PORT, destination IP, and destination PORT.

- The origin IP is required to distinguish between requests from different clients
- The origin PORT is required to distinguish between requests from different processes of one client
- Destination PORT is required to distinguish which processes receive requests from a server.

However, destination IP seems to be only needed up to the network layer, so I wonder why it is included in the TCP socket identifier.

Comment: *"The origin PORT is required to distinguish between requests from different processes of one client"* - No. The same process can have multiple __connections__ with different source ports. Also, TCP is not about "requests" at all, it is an unstructured bidirectional byte stream. A request/response semantic is some pattern which can be implemented on top of this, but this is not the only possible communication pattern.

Comment: That's an unthinkable view! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that: "The client is the one who sends the request to the server and makes the connection through a socket at first."

**The destination IP should be specified to distinguish which server this request is for.** So, the request will be routed through the network to arrive at the server.

Answer (score 0):

A given server machine could be running multiple server sockets, potentially bound to different networks. So, once the network delivers a packet to the server machine, the OS's socket stack would still need to know the source IP/Port and destination IP/Port to deliver the packet to the correct socket buffer.